# webOS 3.0 enyo sqlite Database storage and retrieval

Tags: webos

I am creating an app for webOS in enyo. I have an sqllite database running in the browser properly but how i can find the path of this database?

And how can i retrieve this database?

Is it possible to get whole DB file?

That is very new so I can't get the solution for it.

Any suggestion or help will solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a really good Enyo SQL lite wrapper class that has been developed from the Mojo version by OneCrayon...

https://github.com/onecrayon/database-webos

this is really all you will need, if you read through the code there are some very good notes on how to use it!

Answer (score 1):

Its not really clear what you're attempting to do.

If you use the webSQL interface to generate a db, you can use that same interface to access it.

You cannot really access the sqllite file directly, and its not clear why you would want to.

Or are you saying you already have an sqllite database from some other source and want to be able to open it up in your application via the websql interface?  Thats not currently possible.

Comment: Its to complicated to develop enyo... not got dear.

Comment: It's not complicated, actually is one of the easier mobile platforms to develop for. Would recomend you brush up on JavaScript, and CSS. Give it a couple of weeks and there will be loads of tutorials around the web, the NDA was only lifted on Enyo last week - so us DEV's couldn't talk about it